# Springboot GET request endpoint

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Below I have attached a method in my service layer. It handles a GET request. Below method is working but when testing it in postman, when I am sending a new ID, In the first time of the sending the request it returns a empty array but in the second time when sending the request it returns the array with saved values in t1 and t2 objects. I can't figure out why it is returning an empty array in the first time I am sending the request. Below I have attached my controller and service methods.

```
package com.websafe.ccmsbe.controller;

import com.websafe.ccmsbe.entity.CookieBannerTemplate;
import com.websafe.ccmsbe.service.CookieBannerTemplateService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/template")
@CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:3000")
public class CookieBannerTemplateController {

    @Autowired
    CookieBannerTemplateService cookieBannerTemplateService;

    @GetMapping("getAllTemplates/{websiteID}")
    public List<CookieBannerTemplate> getAllTemplates(@PathVariable(name = "websiteID")Long websiteID){
                return cookieBannerTemplateService.getAllTemplates(websiteID);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class CookieBannerTemplateService {

    @Autowired
    CookieBannerTemplateRepository cookieBannerTemplateRepository;

    @Autowired
    CookieBannerRepository cookieBannerRepository;

    @Autowired
    WebsiteRepository websiteRepository;


  


    public List<CookieBannerTemplate> getAllTemplates(Long websiteID) {
        Website website = websiteRepository.findById(websiteID).orElse(null);
        if (website != null){
            CookieBanner cookieBanner = website.getCookieBanner();
            if( cookieBanner == null) {
                cookieBanner = new CookieBanner();
                cookieBanner.setWebsite(website);
                cookieBanner.setBannerAlignment("Right");
                cookieBanner.setBannerColor("Dark Grey");
                cookieBanner.setBannerPosition("Center");
                cookieBannerRepository.save(cookieBanner);

                int n = website.getPrivacyRegulations().size();
                System.out.println("length = " + n);

                CookieBannerTemplate t1 = new CookieBannerTemplate();
                CookieBannerTemplate t2 = new CookieBannerTemplate();

                t1.setCookieBanner(cookieBanner);
                t1.setTemplateContent("default content");
                t1.setTemplateRegulation("GDPR");
                t1.setTemplateName("Websafe-GDPR");
                cookieBannerTemplateRepository.save(t1);

                t2.setCookieBanner(cookieBanner);
                t2.setTemplateContent("default content");
                t2.setTemplateRegulation("CCPA");
                t2.setTemplateName("Websafe-CCPA");
                cookieBannerTemplateRepository.save(t2);
                
                return cookieBanner.getCookieBannerTemplates();
            }

            return website.getCookieBanner().getCookieBannerTemplates();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If the websiteID is already exist in the cookiebanner table the endpoint works fine. But if the websiteID doesn't exist in the table, in the first time it returns an empty array and in the second time sending the request it works and returns the saved values.

Comment: It is strange that the second call is working, given that the first "if" is wrong.
Do you save any entity in websiteRepository ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *cookieBanner* is null, you create a new CookieBanner, but you don't set it to *website*.
After `cookieBanner = new CookieBanner();`, try `website.setCookieBanner(cookieBanner);` to see if works for you.